# Zig slice of sentinel-terminated array excluding all trailing sentinels

Tags: arrays, slice, sentinel, zig

Given a sentinel-terminated array `[N:0]T` which is only partially filled at the beginning of the array with and unknown amount of entities `n < N`, and the rest is filled with sentinels (`0`), what's the most concise way to grab a slice only containing the first entities before any sentinel?

Here's a code example in linux, where `utsname.release: [64:0]u8` is populated by the OS with the kernel's semantic version string.

```
const std = @import("std");

// ...

    const utsname: std.os.linux.utsname = std.os.uname();
    std.debug.print("utsname.release = '{s}'\n", .{utsname.release});
    std.debug.print("utsname.release.len = {}\n", .{utsname.release.len});
    const utsNameReleaseSlice: []const u8 = &utsname.release;
    std.debug.print("utsNameReleaseSlice = '{s}'\n", .{utsNameReleaseSlice});
    std.debug.print("utsNameReleaseSlice.len = {}\n", .{utsNameReleaseSlice.len});
```

output:

```
utsname.release = '6.6.8-gnu'
utsname.release.len = 64
utsNameReleaseSlice = '6.6.8-gnu'
utsNameReleaseSlice.len = 64
```

In the print above, the string looks ok but it prints out the sentinels which are zero-width characters. When I provide the slice to `std.SemanticVersion.parse` it throws an error when it gets to those sentinel characters.

To fix this I got the index of the first sentinel and took a slice up to there:

```
    const versionStringEnd: usize = std.mem.indexOf(u8, &utsname.release, &[_]u8{0}) orelse utsname.release.len;
    const utsNameReleaseSlice: []const u8 = utsname.release[0..versionStringEnd];
    std.debug.print("utsNameReleaseSlice = '{s}'\n", .{utsNameReleaseSlice});
    std.debug.print("utsNameReleaseSlice.len = {}\n", .{utsNameReleaseSlice.len});
```

output:

```
utsNameReleaseSlice = '6.6.8-gnu'
utsNameReleaseSlice.len = 9
```

Is there a more concise way of getting this slice which ignores sentinels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`std.mem.span`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.span), which does exactly that.

Specifically, with the above example, you would need to cast the sentinel-terminated array as a sentinel-terminated pointer `@as([*:0]const u8, &utsname.release)` and provide that to `std.mem.span`:

```
const utsNameReleaseSlice: []const u8 = std.mem.span(@as([*:0]const u8, &utsname.release));
```